# Is it possible to delete a minus sign from a specific column (the last column) in a text file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Below is part of my file named nvt.gro I want to delete the minus sign "-" in the last column only. I have tried to select the complete column and then try to modify it, but I didn't succeed. Can anyone please tell me how to delete a specific character which is the minus sign in my case in a certain column which is the last column in my case. 
I am using ubuntu text editor. I have tried to select the complete column using the Alt+Ctrl+Shift+End then followed by Ctrl + Shift + right so that I can modify the whole column but I couldn't.

Thanks

GRM in vacuum

192700

```
2794GRM     C311175  17.065  14.579   0.041  0.9776 -0.3700 -0.3156
2794GRM     C411176  16.942  14.650   0.044 -0.2129  0.6799 -0.0069
2795GRM     C111177  16.942  14.792   0.039 -0.1699 -0.1038 -0.0750
2795GRM     C211178  17.065  14.863   0.037  0.4158 -0.0119 -0.4087
2795GRM     C311179  17.069  15.003   0.029 -0.1180 -0.0134 -0.3801
2795GRM     C411180  16.945  15.073   0.020 -1.1317  0.8381 -0.4420
2796GRM     C111181  16.946  15.215   0.009 -0.6160  0.7328  0.3329
2796GRM     C211182  17.069  15.286   0.004  0.4990 -0.4661  0.0473
2796GRM     C311183  17.068  15.428  13.995  1.1753  0.1069  0.4126
2796GRM     C411184  16.942  15.497  13.995  0.1072 -0.1759  1.0031
2797GRM     C111185  16.942  15.640  13.989  0.0772 -0.7484  0.6072
2797GRM     C211186  17.065  15.709  13.987  0.3197  0.7923  0.7660
2797GRM     C311187  17.064  15.851  13.987  0.6508  0.1744  0.8011
2797GRM     C411188  16.941  15.922  13.988 -0.0779 -0.5235  0.4419
2798GRM     C111189  16.940  16.064  13.993 -0.4092 -0.2008  0.0229
2798GRM     C211190  17.064  16.135  13.995 -0.0923 -0.0063 -0.2445
2798GRM     C311191  17.060  16.277  13.996 -0.6767 -0.0982  0.1754
2798GRM     C411192  16.938  16.350  13.991 -0.3535  0.5098 -0.5576
2799GRM     C111193  16.941  16.492  13.990 -1.1218 -0.1434 -0.7878
2799GRM     C211194  17.062  16.566  13.986  0.4727 -0.4516 -0.1352
2799GRM     C311195  17.066  16.708  13.976  0.2361  0.1619  0.0749
2799GRM     C411196  16.944  16.779  13.973  0.0201 -0.3561 -0.0658
2800GRM     C111197  16.944  16.922  13.973 -0.6244 -0.2583  1.1019
2800GRM     C211198  17.065  16.998  13.977 -0.3723 -0.3714  0.1573
2800GRM     C311199  17.063   0.099  13.979 -0.0548 -0.1926 -0.0981
2800GRM     C411200  16.942   0.172  13.971 -0.0881  0.1676 -0.0564
2801G8LE   C6011201   5.831   0.116  10.796 -0.2284  0.5235 -0.4732
2801G8LE   C5711202   5.835   0.256  10.802  0.3394  0.2015 -0.6239
2801G8LE   C5011203   5.941   0.316  10.877  0.2831 -0.4177 -0.4594
2801G8LE   C4011204   5.987   0.424  10.807 -0.0715 -0.4403  0.0066
2801G8LE   C3011205   6.118   0.463  10.803  0.1128  0.6914  0.2241
2801G8LE   C2011206   6.182   0.514  10.694 -0.1651  0.0946 -0.2201
2801G8LE   C1111207   6.315   0.466  10.687 -0.0770  0.3137 -0.3695
2801G8LE    C511208   6.368   0.422  10.571  0.4080  0.4664  0.8689
2801G8LE    C211209   6.443   0.305  10.562  0.0527 -0.6675 -0.2050
2801G8LE    C111210   6.411   0.245  10.447  0.0286 -0.0604 -0.1501
2801G8LE    C311211   6.405   0.108  10.435 -0.4744 -0.0151 -0.6526
2801G8LE    C711212   6.303   0.052  10.359  0.0532  0.0121 -0.2123
2801G8LE   C1411213   6.207   0.134  10.300 -0.0620 -0.3235 -0.2260
2801G8LE    C911214   6.219   0.271  10.295 -0.1192 -0.3422 -0.4145
2801G8LE    C411215   6.317   0.322  10.379  0.1036 -0.1823  0.1164
```

Comment: Yes, you can remove just a leading hypen from column 8 !  What text processing commands have you tried? ... 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255832/49368 provides a similar example. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something truly column-based, then you could use awk ex.

```
awk '{sub(/-/," ",$NF)} 1' file
```

This applies a regular expression **sub**stitution to only the `NF`th column (where `NF` is the number of fields). However this will re-write modified records using the default single-space output field separator - which may mess up the column alignment.

If you have access to [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html), then you can do a similar thing without spoiling the alignment:

```
mlr --nidx put -S '$[NF] =~ "^-(.*)" {$[NF] = " \1"}' file
```

---

Alternatively, you could identify the last column using an anchored extended regular expression like `[^[:blank]]+$`, for example

```
sed -E 's/-([^[:blank:]]+)$/ \1/' file
```

To edit the file in place,

```
sed -i -E 's/-([^[:blank:]]+)$/ \1/' file
```

---

To apply the substitution only to lines that start with one or more decimal digits followed by string G8LE, you can modify the sed expression as follows:

```
/^[0-9]+G8LE/s/-([^[:blank:]]+)$/ \1/
```

Comment: I ran the commands in the terminals and they worked but only in the terminal but the nvt.gro (text file was not modified) it was only modified inside the terminal. How can I do that in the file itself (modify the file itself not just printing the values in the terminal).

Comment: @MohamedAbdelaal the `sed` command can be made to edit the file in place by adding the `-i` switch - see `man sed`. *Some* implementations of `awk` have a similar functionality via an `inplace` module.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. sorry but where exactly in the sed line should I add -i ? or did I misunderstood something ?

Comment: @MohamedAbdelaal please see updated answer

Comment: thank you so much :)

Comment: I have a further question and sorry if I didn't specify it from the beginning. my file in the first column contains 2 different words either GRM or G8LE. is it possible to do the above process only in the lines which contains the G8LE? I was planning to cut the GRM lines and then modify the file and then paste them back. but it will be very helpful if I can remove the minus sign from the last column for the lines which contains G8LE only. ?? Thanks again and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @MohamedAbdelaal see further edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106811/discussion-between-mohamed-abdelaal-and-steeldriver).

Answer (score 2):

Delete/substitute nth character with sed:

```
$ sed 's/./ /61' file
```

<sup>will print the changes to the console.</sup>

Or inplace substitution:

```
$ sed -i 's/./ /61' file
```

<sup>will save the changes back to the file.</sup>

before:

```
2794GRM     C311175  17.065  14.579   0.041  0.9776 -0.3700 -0.3156
2794GRM     C411176  16.942  14.650   0.044 -0.2129  0.6799 -0.0069
2795GRM     C111177  16.942  14.792   0.039 -0.1699 -0.1038 -0.0750
^           ^        ^                      ^       ^       ^ 
1           13       22 ...                 45      53      61
```

After:

```
2794GRM     C311175  17.065  14.579   0.041  0.9776 -0.3700  0.3156
2794GRM     C411176  16.942  14.650   0.044 -0.2129  0.6799  0.0069
2795GRM     C111177  16.942  14.792   0.039 -0.1699 -0.1038  0.0750
```

Comment: ...and no fingerprint on the screen...

Comment: Can you please describe which character I am replacing by which and in which column and in which line ? sorry but I need more details to try it.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the tr command very useful

```
$ tr -d -
```

If you are going to read the data in, modify it and create a new report, this is the way I chose to do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
_abs() {
    echo $1 | tr -d -
}

while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8; do
    newf8=$(_abs $f8)
    echo "$f1     $f2  $f3  $f4  $f5  $f6  $f7  $newf8" >> newreport.txt
done < data
```

Data In

```
2794GRM     C311175  17.065  14.579   0.041  0.9776 -0.3700 -0.3156
2794GRM     C411176  16.942  14.650   0.044 -0.2129  0.6799 -0.0069
2795GRM     C111177  16.942  14.792   0.039 -0.1699 -0.1038 -0.0750
2795GRM     C211178  17.065  14.863   0.037  0.4158 -0.0119 -0.4087
```

Data out

```
2794GRM     C311175  17.065  14.579  0.041  0.9776 -0.3700  0.3156
2794GRM     C411176  16.942  14.650  0.044 -0.2129  0.6799  0.0069
2795GRM     C111177  16.942  14.792  0.039 -0.1699 -0.1038  0.0750
2795GRM     C211178  17.065  14.863  0.037  0.4158 -0.0119  0.4087
```

Comment: What if I want to modify the same file instead of creating a new one ?

Comment: If it is your program that is creating the file in the first place, simply add the function defined in my example to your source code and reference it like I did in my example.